# Microchip XC8 warnings "conversion to shorter data type" and "implicit conversion signed to unsigned"

Tags: c, microchip, xc8

I'm using MPLABX 3.20 with xc8 1.35 compiler for a PIC18F2420 and i've got two stranges warnings that i don't understand :

Here is one of the source code that generate the warning

```
9  void write(Pin _Pin, char value)
10  {
11     if( value == 1)
12     {
13         (*((_Pin.Reg)+ 5*sizeof(char))) |=(1<<_Pin.Bit);
14     }
15     else
16     {
17         (*((_Pin.Reg)+ 5*sizeof(char))) &= ~(1<<_Pin.Bit);
18     }
19 }
```

Here is the Struct Pin i use :

```
typedef unsigned char *SFR;

typedef struct 
{
    SFR Reg;
    unsigned char Bit;
    SFR ReadReg;

}Pin;
```

this code is used to offer a simple way to use the pins

I have the following warnings :

Pin.c:13: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion

Pin.c:17: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion

...

Pin.c:17: warning: (752) conversion to shorter data type

the both values are unsigned char so why do i have these warnings ?

Answer (score 1):

> the both values are unsigned char so why do i have these warnings ?

A helpful approach for yourself would be: assume that you're wrong. Where can you be wrong? Obviously since you have the warnings, the values cannot be unsigned.

Now let's analyze how they might not be unsigned. `_Pin.Bit` is a unsigned value. But we don't use it. We use it in an integer expression, whose type is - well - simply `int`:

The expression `(1<<_Pin.Bit)` is of type `int`.

The expression `~(1<<_Pin.Bit)` is of type `int` and moreover you're discarding its non-zero sign bits when converting to a unsigned char, prompting the second warning for line 17.

Comment: Yeah, the OP could try appending `u` to those literals and seeing what happens. I would also caution that signed `1 << [bits in the platform's int - 1]` _was_ undefined behaviour and is now implementation-defined, so if `_Pin.Bit == bits in OP's int`, then anything can happen.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand well : 
The shifting operation use a int platform,
a int is signed by default, 
this is why i have thoses warnings 
So is there a way to tell XC8 to use a char to make the shift ?
@underscore_d what do you mean by appending u ?

Comment: @shangaorenfilehunter I guess you should read up on how C determines types as it evaluates an expression.

Comment: @shangaorenfilehunter "append" ~= suffix. simply try adding a `u` at the end of your currently signed literals and see what happens. to be clear, the literals have type, _not_ the shift. and yes, a little more background reading about literals, integral promotion, etc would clear a lot of this up.

Comment: Okay, adding a u cleared the signed/unsigned problem, thanks @underscore_d

Comment: @shangaorenfilehunter Good to hear and thanks for letting me know.

Comment: According to XC8's manual the shortest size of a literal is a int even for a binary or hexadecimal value so i think there is no way to suppress this warning

Comment: @shangaorenfilehunter You can explicitly cast the expression to a desired type, and the compiler should should up then: `... = (unsigned char)(~(1<<_Pin.Bit));`

Comment: No i've already try to cast to unsigned char but the warning still there
        (*((_Pin.Reg)+ 5*sizeof(char))) = (*((_Pin.Reg)+ 5*sizeof(char)))& (unsigned char)(~(1u<<_Pin.Bit));

give me this :
Pin.c:18: warning: (752) conversion to shorter data type

but this look related to the ~ because i don't have this on the over line